# What type of JavaScript term/definition fits this?

Tags: javascript, methods

I was reading the [MDN documentation on JavaScript classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and came across an example of assigning values that I did not understand. The lines in question were not explained because the page was simply explaining something else (static methods). I am fascinated though with how it worked and what this would be officially called so that I can research it further.

```
 class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  static distance(a, b) {
    const dx = a.x - b.x;
    const dy = a.y - b.y;
    return Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  }
}
```

What I don't understand specifically is the `a.x`, `b.x`, `a.y` and `b.y`. I wouldn't consider this dot notation because dot notation is defined as *"In JavaScript, one can access properties using the dot notation..."*. So if this is not dot notation, then what term would apply to the value of `x` and `y` being assigned to `a` and `b`?

Wouldn't the letters `a` and `b` in line -

```
static distance(a, b)
```

technically be called "parameters" which is clearly defined as something other than a property. And since they are "parameters", then the word "property" would not apply, therefore the official definition of dot notation does not apply.

Definition of parameter: *Parameters are variables listed as a part of the function definition*

Definition of property:  *has a value, which may or may not be writable*

Definition of dot notation: *In JavaScript, one can access properties using the dot notation...*

Comment: That *is* dot notation; for example, you're accessing the `x` property on `a`.

Comment: Second confirmation: that’s dot notation. What made you not want to consider it that?

Comment: Third one, it is dot notation.

Comment: I see, I thought the definition didn't match up to this example, but i guess it does.

Comment: I just thought that "a" and "b" weren't properties, but they where parameters. Thats why I asked. I never saw the "a" parameter or "b" parameter set by anything before a.x and so on.

Comment: Right – `a` and `b` are parameters. `a.x` refers to the property `x` of the parameter `a`.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not parameters, they are arguments, you can name it Michael_Jackson and Elvis_Presley if you want, but they must concern a Point class

Comment: @Ry- If you take the hold off, i have found the answer to my question and would like to post as a answer please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was due to a lack of understanding of how object instantiation works and how this object can be referenced in a static method. The `a` and `b` on line

```
static distance(a,b)
```

are not typical parameters that simply take a single value as I thought. They are actually receiving a complete instantiated object reference upon said objects creation. Therefore the dot notation of `a.x` is indeed a 'dot notation' reference to a value that is assigned to a name or property inside of an object. Also what I found confusing was how

`b.x` and `b.y`

would have not been created yet upon the first objects instantiation. Apparently a "helper method" such as a *static method* programatically knows to wait until all the parameters are filled before the method can produce a return result. And it knows this by having all its parameters filled with objects.

Comment: “are not typical parameters that simply take a single value as I thought” – they are. Objects are single values. The parameters here work the same as parameters to any other function.

Comment: @Ry- Even in the above example it is clear to me that the object instantiated has 2 properties with 2 values inside of it. so how is it possible only 1 value is passed to the parameter of a? I would think grammatically this can be described as having 3 values total, the object name and the 2 values associated with it. Also my answer does confirm that this is "dot notation" which is the specific question I asked from the very beginning.

Comment: A proper answer by someone else should go deeper than that, addressing the root misconception that led you to believe it wasn’t dot notation in the first place… except nobody was ever able to figure that out, hence comments. If your self-answer doesn’t include that, that’s fine – it just shouldn’t include a bunch of objectively wrong stuff, like that `a` and `b` aren’t “typical parameters” or that the concept of a “helper method” that “knows to wait” exists at all.

Comment: “3 values total, the object name and the 2 values associated with it” might be a helpful way to describe it in some context, but in the context of “not typical parameters that simply take a single value”, it is not a correct distinction.

Comment: @Ry- I understand and thank you! I will strive to understand this subject better